# Htaccess RewriteRule giving Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess RewriteRule rule for my site, I have tried it in two ways, first one is working while second is not working. Here is my code

Its working

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ /article-detail.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Its not working (Just using folder)

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ /article/article-detail.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Second way is giving internal server error. Can you help please.

Comment: Add a rule `RewriteBase /article/`

Comment: Where to add ? i just added one life before, but its not working

Comment: @Gulshan can you please explain this

Comment: Can you provide your full htaccess?

Comment: @pr1nc3 sorry! i cant provide you the full htaccess file. I can just provide this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ /article/article-detail.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Your second rule is not working because your regex pattern is matching both source and target URLs which results in a rewrite loop and causes `500` error.

You can add a `RewriteCond` to prevent this behavior:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ article/article-detail.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Perfectly working!!! can you please explain your answere by explaining `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteRule ^article/(.+)` instead of `RewriteRule ^article/(.*)` ?

Comment: `.+` matches 1 or more characters instead of 0 or more as in `.*`. `RewriteCond` with `!-f` makes sure request if not for a file and `!-d` make sure request is not for a directory.

Comment: You are genius Man! Thanks